# Iron-router, Router.go() doesn't full render a template

Tags: javascript, meteor, iron-router, meteor-blaze

I have a login system with the following layout :

```
<template name="loginLayout"> 
    <div class="container">
      <div class="flat-form">
        <ul class="tabs">
          <li> <a id="login"          class="{{#if isRouteActive 'login' }}active{{/if}}"         href="{{ pathFor 'login' }}">Login</a> </li>
          <li> <a id="registration"   class="{{#if isRouteActive 'registration' }}active{{/if}}"  href="{{ pathFor 'registration'  }}">Register</a> </li>
          <li> <a id="resetPassword"  class="{{#if isRouteActive 'resetPassword' }}active{{/if}}" href="{{ pathFor 'resetPassword' }}">Reset Password</a> </li>
        </ul>
        {{> yield }}
    </div>
    </div> </template>
```

According to which link a user hits, meteor renders the correct template in the yield field. 
This works fine, but when a user logs in, the private page is rendered within this layout which is wrong. I don't understand why this is happening, if I specify the layout only for the login routes.

Routes file :

```
Router.map( function () {
  this.route( 'login',  
            { 
              path : '/login',  
              layoutTemplate: 'loginLayout',
              yieldTemplate : 'login',
              data : { 
                appName : "test", 
                welcomeMessage  : "test." 
              }
            }
    );

  this.route( 'registration',  
            { 
              path : '/registration',  
              layoutTemplate: 'loginLayout',
              yieldTemplate:'registration',
              data : {}
            }
    );

  this.route( 'resetPassword',  
            { 
              path : '/resetPassword',  
              layoutTemplate: 'loginLayout',
              yieldTemplate : 'resetPassword',
              data : {}
            }
    );
  this.route('library');
});

var mustBeSignedIn = function(pause) {
  if (!(Meteor.user() || Meteor.loggingIn())) {
    Router.go('login');
    pause();
  }
};

Router.onBeforeAction(mustBeSignedIn, {except: ['login', 'registration', 'resetPassword']});
```

Login.js

```
Template.login.events({

    'submit #login-form' : function(e, t){
      e.preventDefault();
      // retrieve the input field values
      var userName = t.find('#login-email').value
        , password = t.find('#login-password').value;

        Meteor.loginWithPassword(userName, password, function(err){
        if (err) { 
          console.log("Error when loggin ");
          console.log(err.reason);
        } else {
          console.log("user logged in");
          /***** REDIRECT ******/ 
          Router.go('library');
        }
      });
         return false; 
      }
 });
```

logi.js template :

```
<template name="login"> 
<div id="login" class="form-action">
  <h1>Login on {{ appName }} </h1>
    <p> {{ welcomeMessage }} </p>
    <form id="login-form">
      <ul>
        <li> <input id="login-email" type="text" placeholder="Username" /></li>
        <li> <input id="login-password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /></li>
        <li> <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="button" /></li>
      </ul>
    </form>
</div>
</template>
```

I have also noticed that when I use the method "go" to redirect a user to a given route, the data field is reset. Whereas, when I write down the url every thing works fine.

[Full source](https://github.com/giuse88/meteor-apps/tree/master/lending_library/login/client)

Comment: Do you have a login template defined?

Comment: yes. sure! I can add it here

Answer (score 1):

The way it worked for me was to create an additional controller for my major layout and render my header and footer template again with and *layoutTemplate*, *yieldTemplate* and *action: function(){}*.

Here an example route:

```
Router.route('einstellungen', function() { // settings
  this.render('Settings', {
    to: 'interfaceContainer'
  });
}, {
  controller: 'InterfaceController'
});
```

And **only after adding the following code**, Router.go('/einstellungen'); works in a way that the entire layout plus yield layouts are rendered.

```
InterfaceController = RouteController.extend({
  layoutTemplate: 'interfaceLayout',
  yieldTemplates: {
    'Header': {
      to: 'interfaceHeader'
    },
    'Footer': {
      to: 'interfaceFooter'
    }
  },
  action: function() {
    this.render('Header', {
      to: 'interfaceHeader'
    });
    this.render('Footer', {
      to: 'interfaceFooter'
    });
  }
});
```

*I also added:*

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'interfaceLayout',
  yieldTemplates: {
    'Header': {
      to: 'interfaceHeader'
    },
    'Footer': {
      to: 'interfaceFooter'
    }
  }
});
```

But this does not seem to have any impact on Router.go();

*See also:*

> https://forums.meteor.com/t/custom-layout-for-a-specific-route-not-displaying-with-iron-router/5758
>
> https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router/blob/devel/Guide.md#creating-route-controllers